# How can I return to fullscreen mode after alt tab?

Tags: 15.04, shortcuts, minecraft, fullscreen

How can I return to full screen in minecraft in Ubuntu?

If I press <kbd>F11</kbd> minimizes it to window mode and I can use firefox and other things but if <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> out of fullscreen mode, only way to get back to is to force restart the PC.

It play minecraft sounds, but I can't return to fullscreen mode.

Sometimes it allows you to see applications that are running and returning to them by clicking it.

Workaround: if i can get login text terminal then: ps -A and find java kill that process... homewer this does not fix issue that i cant return full screen.

Comment: And alt+tab doesn't work?

Comment: It disappears from alt tab list of programs, only workaround is to take power cable off :(... using default unity desktop.

Comment: It might be a bug. https://help.mojang.com/customer/portal/articles/409117-where-can-i-view-or-submit-bugs-

Comment: What happens if you use super+tab? I've found with a couple of applications that they don't appear in the alt+tab list but they do appear in the launcher

Comment: What is super+tab?

Comment: Super key also know windowslogokey + tab = super tab.